# Kepler's Mysterium Cosmographicum with regular polygons: in which nesting order?

Tags: astronomy, geometry

Kepler tried to use regular polygons before using the 3D platonic solids in his Mysterium Cosmographicum.
My question is: which regular polygons did Kepler try to use and in what nesting order?

Comment: @Senex, this is the 3d model. my question is about 2d models using regular polygons not regular polyhedra! take a look  here:  https://medium.com/@mansirjohn/the-mysterium-cosmographicum-27db575526fc

Comment: Apologies -- misread your question. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the preface to *Mysterium Cosmographicum*, Kepler wrote that he first saw that an equilateral triangle fit well between the orbits of Saturn and Jupiter.

Noting that this triangle was the first of the regular polygons, he tried to continue the sequence with a square in the second interval (between Jupiter and Mars), a pentagon in the third (between Mars and Earth), and a hexagon in the fourth (between Earth and Venus).

He had already noticed that there was an incorrect fit between Jupiter and Mars, so he tried nesting a square, triangle, and pentagon in this interval. (The order is not clear from the text.) This is the sum of the information he gave on his attempts. He noted that finding a correct combination of polygons for each case would be "an endless pursuit of detail" ("Infinitum est singula persequi").

He abandoned using polygons largely because they did not give a mathematical reason why there were exactly six planets (per the state of knowledge at the time). Since there are exactly five regular solids, they corresponded one-to-one with the intervals between six orbits and so did give such a reason.

**References**

- For a summary with explanation of Kepler's attempt to use polygons, see pp.46–49 of J.V. Field, *Kepler's Geometrical Cosmology.* Bloomsbury, 2013. ISBN: 978-1-4725-0703-7.
- For Kepler's own account in the preface to the *Mysterium Cosmographicum*, see pp.11–12 of Kepler, [*Gesammelte Werke*, vol.I](http://publikationen.badw.de/de/002334737). Munich: C.H. Beck, 1938; or pp.65–67 of the translation by A.M. Duncan, *The Secret of the Universe.* Abaris Books, 1981. ISBN: 978-0-913870-64-8.

Comment: Quoting from pp. 8-9 of the edition of 1621: "Nam circuli triangulo inscripti radius est circumscripti radii dimidium. Proportio inter utrumque circulum videbatur ad oculum pene similis illi, quae est inter Saturnum & Iovem: & triagulum prima erat figuratum, sicut Saturnus & Iupiter primi Planetae. Tentavi statim quadrangulo distantiam secundam Martius & Iovis, quinquangulo tertiam, sexangulo quartam. Cumque etiam oculi reclamarent in secunda distantia, que est inter Iovem & Martem quadratum triangulo & quinquangulo adjunxit. Infinitum est singula persequi."

Comment: Google's scan of J. Kepler, *Mysterium Cosmographicum.* Frankfurt: Erasmus Kempfer 1621 is [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Prodromus_dissertationum_cosmographicaru/owHM6OeIL_IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Saturnus&pg=PA8&printsec=frontcover).